# Rspec fails to run on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ubuntu-12.04, rspec-rails

I'm dealing with a problem that has been annoying me for quite a while. For some reason, I can't get rspec started on my local machine. I've tried various approaches to install and run it, but none of them worked.
I am running Ruby on Rails 2.3.5 with Ruby 1.8.7 on a git repository using bundler.

First of all, I tried to install rspec as a gem. For that purpose, I added the following entries to my Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '=1.3.0'
  gem "rspec-rails", "=1.3.2"
end
...
group :cucumber do
  gem 'rspec', '=1.3.0'
  gem "rspec-rails", "=1.3.2"  
end
```

When I check with

> gem list

I get to see

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
(...)
rspec (1.3.0)
rspec-rails (1.3.2)
```

So, it must be there. Then I created a spec file in /spec/model/bookmark_step.rb. But when I try to run it with

> rspec spec/model/bookmark_spec.rb

I get

```
The program 'rspec' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby-rspec-core
```

When using

> bundle exec spec

I get

> bundler: command not found: rspec
>   Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`

Ok, so far so bad. Let's try something else. Why not install from the ubuntu sources (I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04):

> sudo apt-get install ruby-rspec-core
>
> Suggested packages:
>   ruby-rspec
>   The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   ruby-rspec-core
>   0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.

Ok, let's roll by typing

> rspec spec/model/bookmark_spec.rb

Guess what I'm getting ...

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant RSpec::Core::Formatters (NameError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec_spinner-2.0.0/lib/rspec_spinner/base.rb:12
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec_spinner-2.0.0/lib/rspec_spinner.rb:4
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
from (...) Workspace/config/boot.rb:116:in `load_gems'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from (...)  Workspace/config/environment.rb:28
from (...)  Workspace/spec/model/../spec_helper.rb:4:in `require'
from (...)  Workspace/spec/model/../spec_helper.rb:4
from (...)  Workspace/spec/model/bookmark_spec.rb:2:in `require'
from (...)  Workspace/spec/model/bookmark_spec.rb:2
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `map'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
from /usr/bin/rspec:4
```

Ok, that last thing might be a version mismatch. I guess ubuntu installs rspec for rails 3 while I need rspec for rails 2.3.5. But I've tried a lot to make it work. I suppose that was the wrong way, anyway, so i eventually stopped looking for the exact cause of that last error message.

Does anyone have a guess what else I could try? Or maybe something I should change?

Comment: Did you try `bundle exec rspec` (instead of `bundle exec spec`)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried both `spec` and `rspec`. With ruby-rspec-core installed from the Ubuntu sources, it kind of runs, but doesn't really execute the given specs. When I type in `bundle exec rspec`, the result then looks like that: `<Proc:0xb731cd80@/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/core/configuration.rb:50>} is excluding everything?


Finished in 0.00003 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures`

Comment: And using `bundle exec rspec spec/model/bookmark_spec.rb` gives me the error mentioned earlier ...

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, I've noticed on Ubuntu that the environment isn't loaded early enough to trigger bundler loading the test group gems. I haven't figured out the root cause yet but running my tests like this works:

`RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec`

Answer (score 0):

We've been using the following for our rails 2.3.14 application. I guess it should work for 2.3.5 too...

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", "1.3.4"
  gem "steak"
  gem "factory_girl", "2.6.4"
  gem "database_cleaner"
end

group :test do
  gem "mocha"
  gem "capybara", "~> 0.3.9"
end
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I tried that one, too. 
The outcome is the following error: `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant RSpec::Core::Formatters (NameError) from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing' (...)`. However, it's defintily installed on my system. I checked with `gem list`: `rspec (1.3.1, 1.3.0)
rspec-rails (1.3.4, 1.3.2)` It seems to be less a version problem and much more an installation issue ...